# MenuItemCompat not working with support lib version 26.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, menuitem, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I am getting an unsupportedOperationException on MenuItemCompat when I upgraded my support library version to 26.1.0 (which is mandatory for lifecycle components). I changed it to use MenuItem as recommended in android docs but I still get the same error. Tried rebuilding, cleaning project. Nothing helps. I also tried using SupportMenuItem as suggested in some answer on SO. Even that didn't help. I **cannot** revert to my older support lib version since I have to use lifecycle components. Please help me!

I know this might be treated as a duplicate but I have been trying for days to solve this issue and none of the answers on SO are relevant to my usecase. Most of the people just suggest decreasing the support lib version but that, one, is not a scalable solution, and two, does not solve my issue because I have to use this version at the least.

These are the logs:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()
                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemImpl.java:740)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItemCompat.java:464)
```

Comment: `none of the answers` Please provide links to what you already tried. `I am getting an unsupportedOperationException` When? Post the code that actually triggered the exception.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html this is supposed to be fixed in 26.0.0. Make sure all your support libs are the same version.